# Gradle task for debugg apk on start

Tags: android, gradle, task, apk

I have a big android application, and I need to debug in on start. 
I don't have a task for only launching the app with debugger mode enabled. 
It is possible to configure the Gradle task for only running the application in debugger mode?

**EDIT:**
I found the solution in source code

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
}
```

but I don't have the possibility to control when waiting and when not.

Answer (score 0):

I founded solution: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig

In Android studio:

1. Create new run/debug configuration template
2. Remove gradle make
3. Pick new configuration and debug!

[image: pick konfiguration]